# /_api/web/sitegroups/GetByName('GroupName')

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, groups, flow, power-automate

We want to have a form in which a site member can request to add a team member, which is then automated.

In power automate we need the ID of the group:

```
/_api/web/sitegroups/GetByName('Test IRE Site Template Members')
```

This gives the data back with the ID and the group name, but how can I get the ID so I can use it in the next call to add the user to the group?

In the next REST API call I add the user by the following, having `name_member comming` in from the SharePoint List:

```
{"_metadata":{"type":"SP.User"},"loginName":"@{triggerOutputs()?['body/name_member/Claims']}"}
```

API response:

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
        "Vary": "Origin,Accept-Encoding",
        "X-SharePointHealthScore": "1",
        "X-SP-SERVERSTATE": "ReadOnly=0",
        "DATASERVICEVERSION": "3.0",
        "SPClientServiceRequestDuration": "14",
        "SPRequestGuid": "46ecf39f-1009-3000-295e-6c26effc6471",
        "request-id": "46ecf39f-1009-3000-295e-6c26effc6471",
        "MS-CV": "n/PsRgkQADApXmwm7/xkcQ.0",
        "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000,max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
        "X-FRAME-OPTIONS": "SAMEORIGIN,DENY",
        "Content-Security-Policy": "frame-ancestors 'self' teams.microsoft.com *.teams.microsoft.com *.skype.com *.teams.microsoft.us local.teams.office.com *.powerapps.com *.yammer.com *.officeapps.live.com *.office.com *.stream.azure-test.net *.microsoftstream.com;",
        "MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices": "16.0.0.21715",
        "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff,nosniff",
        "X-MS-InvokeApp": "1; RequireReadOnly",
        "x-ms-request-id": "46ecf39f-1009-3000-295e-6c26effc6471",
        "Cache-Control": "no-store, max-age=0, private",
        "P3P": "CP=\"ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI\"",
        "Set-Cookie": "ARRAffinity=a703f806325944e1ff92f5b6964fbc06b4fdf5647d48c76a29966c392ea989b9;Path=/;HttpOnly;Secure;Domain=sharepointonline-ne.azconn-ne.p.azurewebsites.net,ARRAffinitySameSite=a703f806325944e1ff92f5b6964fbc06b4fdf5647d48c76a29966c392ea989b9;Path=/;HttpOnly;SameSite=None;Secure;Domain=sharepointonline-ne.azconn-ne.p.azurewebsites.net",
        "X-AspNet-Version": "4.0.30319",
        "X-Powered-By": "ASP.NET",
        "Timing-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "x-ms-apihub-cached-response": "true",
        "Date": "Tue, 28 Sep 2021 13:28:20 GMT",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; odata=verbose; charset=utf-8",
        "Expires": "Mon, 13 Sep 2021 13:28:20 GMT",
        "Last-Modified": "Tue, 28 Sep 2021 13:28:20 GMT",
        "Content-Length": "811"
    },
    "body": {
        "d": {
            "__metadata": {
                "id": "https://bamgroup.sharepoint.com/sites/025556/_api/Web/SiteGroups/GetById(5)",
                "uri": "https://bamgroup.sharepoint.com/sites/025556/_api/Web/SiteGroups/GetById(5)",
                "type": "SP.Group"
            },
            "Owner": {
                "__deferred": {
                    "uri": "https://bamgroup.sharepoint.com/sites/025556/_api/Web/SiteGroups/GetById(5)/Owner"
                }
            },
            "Users": {
                "__deferred": {
                    "uri": "https://bamgroup.sharepoint.com/sites/025556/_api/Web/SiteGroups/GetById(5)/Users"
                }
            },
            "Id": 5,
            "IsHiddenInUI": false,
            "LoginName": "Test IRE Site Template Members",
            "Title": "Test IRE Site Template Members",
            "PrincipalType": 8,
            "AllowMembersEditMembership": true,
            "AllowRequestToJoinLeave": false,
            "AutoAcceptRequestToJoinLeave": false,
            "Description": null,
            "OnlyAllowMembersViewMembership": false,
            "OwnerTitle": "Test IRE Site Template Owners",
            "RequestToJoinLeaveEmailSetting": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the SharePoint group Id from API response (`body`) using **Parse JSON** action like below:

[image]

**Send HTTP Request action configuration**:

- Method: GET
- Uri:

```
_api/web/sitegroups/GetByName('Flow Owners')?$select=Title,Id
```

Where `Flow Owners` is group name.

**Parse JSON action configuration**:

- Content: `body` from above action
- Schema:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "d": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "Id": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "Title": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**:

You can get SharePoint group ID in `groupId` variable like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks mate, I now get the Json parsing bit. Just couldn't get my head around that one.

Q: Are you the Ganesh Sanap that works at TCS?

Comment: No, I don't work at TCS. You can find more about me at [here](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/about/) or see my [SE profile](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/69998/ganesh-sanap?tab=profile).